# Как сделать так чтобы после прокрутки страницы останавливалось видео

Tags: javascript, видео

Помогите.
Как сделать так, чтобы после прокрутки видео ставилось на стоп, либо пропадало?

[вот сайт](http://project2772388.tilda.ws/page25438745.html)

```
   var video;
window.onload = function() {
 video = document.getElementById("zeromp4video");
}
$(document).on('click', '.PlayPauseVideo', function() {
 if (video.paused) {
   video.play();
 } else {
   video.pause();
 }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Почитайте про `Intersection Observer API`. Создайте событие, которое произойдет, когда контейнер видео покинет область видимости, и затем делайте с видео что захотите.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я тебя обожаю))